# Сделать выборку данных

Tags: php, mysql

Есть две базы данных, одна с заказами "wp_12ae_evpl_orders_places", а другая с категориями на эти заказы "Event", в каждой таблице есть столбец "event_id", как мне сделать выборку заказов из "wp_12ae_evpl_orders_places" по "event_id" из "Event".
Сам могу сделать выборку только из таблицы с заказами:

```
$event_id = "2804";
$stats_order = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_12ae_evpl_orders_places WHERE event_id = $event_id" );
```

Но как сделать, чтобы запрос находил все "event_id" в таблице "Event" и только с этими id выводил запросы.

Массив таблицы "Event" на данный момент:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [event_id] => 2804
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [event_id] => 2806
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [event_id] => 2808
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [event_id] => 2810
        )

)
```

Comment: Пробовал сделать ```SELECT op.*, e.* FROM wp_12ae_evpl_orders_places op LEFT JOIN Event e ON op.event_id = e.event_id``` но выводит все заказы из таблицы wp_12ae_evpl_orders_places.

Comment: INNER JOIN тебе скорее всего нужен SELECT 
     *.*
FROM 
     t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON event_id; вот куча примеров https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx